# Applying reduction operation using Thrust subject to a boolean condition

Tags: cuda, thrust

I want to use  `thrust::reduce` to find the max value in an array A. However, `A[i]`should only be chosen as the max if it also satisfies a particular boolean condition in another array B. For example, B[i] should be true. Is their a version of thrust::reduce that does this. I looked at the documentation and found only following API;

```
thrust::reduce(begin,end, default value, operator)
```

However, i was curious is their a version more suitable to my problem?

EDIT: Compilation fails in last line!

```
      typedef thrust::device_ptr<int> IntIterator;
      typedef thrust::device_ptr<float> FloatIterator;
      typedef thrust::tuple<IntIterator,FloatIterator> IteratorTuple;
      typedef thrust::zip_iterator<IteratorTuple> myZipIterator;
      thrust::device_ptr<int> deviceNBMInt(gpuNBMInt);
    thrust::device_ptr<int> deviceIsActive(gpuIsActive);
    thrust::device_ptr<float> deviceNBMSim(gpuNBMSim);

    myZipIterator iter_begin = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(deviceIsActive,deviceNBMSim));
    myZipIterator iter_end = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(deviceIsActive + numRow,deviceNBMSim + numRow));
    myZipIterator result =  thrust::max_element(iter_begin, iter_end, Predicate());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. I guess you should take a look at [Extrema](http://thrust.github.com/doc/group__extrema.html#ga15bc459d66e289d99a789b99594f7339) And [Zip iterator](http://thrust.github.com/doc/classthrust_1_1zip__iterator.html)

Something like this should do the trick (not sure if this code works out of the box):

```
typedef thrust::device_ptr<bool>  BoolIterator;
typedef thrust::device_ptr<float>  ValueIterator;

BoolIterator bools_begin, bools_end;
ValueIterator values_begin, values_end; 
// initialize these pointers
// ...

typedef thrust::tuple<BoolIterator, ValueIterator> IteratorTuple;
typedef thrust::tuple<bool, value> DereferencedIteratorTuple;
typedef thrust::zip_iterator<IteratorTuple> ZipIterator;

ZipIterator iter_begin(thrust::make_tuple(bools_begin, values_begin));
ZipIterator iter_end(thrust::make_tuple(bools_end, values_end));

struct Predicate
{
  __host__ __device__ bool operator () 
                      (const DereferencedIteratorTuple& lhs, 
                       const DereferencedIteratorTuple& lhs) 
  {
    using thrust::get;
    if (get<0>(lhs) && get<0>(rhs) ) return get<1>(lhs) < get<1>(rhs); else
    return ! get<0>(lhs) ;
  }
};

ZipIterator result =  thrust::max_element(iter_begin, iter_end, Predicate());
```

Or you may consider similar technique with zip iterator with `thrust::reduce`. Or you can try with [inner_product](http://thrust.github.com/doc/group__transformed__reductions.html#ga8fcc4e5a71e784f1f32af89ab5a42e35) Not sure what will work faster.

Comment: What does get<0>(lhs) mean. Also, if the if condition evaluates to false, what happens?

Comment: @Programmer Sorry, it should be `thrust::get<0>(lhs)`. Described here http://thrust.github.com/doc/group__tuple.html#ga4512fb8e91a457663ce15cb72b5ccd9e

Comment: What happens if the `if` condition evaluates to false?

Comment: I guess I overoptimized the code. This is 'less than' predicate. `if` condition evaluates false means one or bool flags are false, so we need to exclude corresponding value. So we check if `lhs` argument should be excluded (`thrust::get<0>(lhs) == false`) and if that is true predicate return `true`, meaning '`lhs` is lesser than `rhs`'. If (`thrust::get<0>(lhs) == true`) , than rhs component should be excluded and predicate returns false, meaning '`lhs` is not lesser than `rhs`'

Comment: I was wrapping a raw ptr into a device ptr to use `thrust::max_element`. I was curious if 'thrust::device_vector<type>::iterator' works for device_ptr. That is, can we define iterators for device pointers

Comment: Since all thrust algorithms are templates, you can use device_ptr instead of iterators. Remember that iterator is generalization of pointer by definition. :)

Comment: But how would your suggested code change if we were to use device_ptr :)

Comment: Subtitute all `thrust::device_vector<blah_blah>::iterator` with `device_ptr<blah_blah>` and fix `iter_begin` and `iter_end`. And I've found a bug in code example. You should dereference the results of `get<>()` since it will return iterator or pointer. (I've fixed it)

Comment: Okay! But can you form a thrust::tuple using 2 device_ptr?If not ,you also cannot form the zip iterator. I will be really obliged if you could modify the code to show me the change since I am a little short on time

Comment: Though I have accepted your answer, my version of your code does not compile. I have modified the original question to show you my code. I will be highly obliged if you could take a quick look and let me know if I am making any foolish errors

Comment: I've fixed the code in my post. That was not a foolish mistake. That was my mistake. My predicate used wrong argument types. It should take derferenced iterator type, but zip iterator is too clever. 'Dereferencing returns a tuple built from the dereferenced iterators in the iterator tuple.' (From thrust/zip_iterator.h line 186) Never expected this.