# Understanding binary predicates in Thrust

Tags: c++, c, thrust

In response to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988603/applying-reduction-operation-using-thrust-subject-to-a-boolean-condition/13989078#13989078) , someone gave me the following code:

```
thrust::device_vector<bool> bools;
thrust::device_vector<float> values;

typedef thrust::device_vector<bool>::iterator   BoolIterator;
typedef thrust::device_vector<float>::iterator  ValueIterator;
typedef thrust::tuple<BoolIterator, ValueIterator> IteratorTuple;
typedef thrust::zip_iterator<IteratorTuple> ZipIterator;

ZipIterator iter_begin(thrust::make_tuple(bools.begin(), values.begin()));
ZipIterator iter_end(thrust::make_tuple(bools.end(), values.end()));

struct Predicate
{
  __host__ __device__ bool operator () 
                      (const IteratorTuple& lhs, const IteratorTuple& lhs) 
  {
    if (get<0>(lhs) && get<0>(rhs) ) return get<1>(lhs) <= get<1>(rhs); else
    return ! get<0>(lhs) ;
  }
};

ZipIterator result =  thrust::max_element(iter_begin, iter_end, Predicate());
```

I want to understand the Predicate struct. what happens if operator returns false? Which value gets selected? What happens if operator returns true? Which value gets selected?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to implement 'lesser than' predicate. It should return `true` if lhs <= rhs and false otherwise. Additionally you requested to exclude values by boolean flags stored in second array, so it checks it.

From my comment:

I guess I overoptimized the code. This is 'less than' predicate. `if` condition evaluates `false` means one or bool flags are `false`, so we need to exclude corresponding value. So we check if `lhs` argument should be excluded `(thrust::get<0>(lhs) == false)` and if that is true predicate return true, meaning 'lhs is lesser than rhs'. If `(thrust::get<0>(lhs) == true)` , than `rhs` component should be excluded and predicate returns false, meaning 'lhs is not lesser than rhs'

I collapsed the following code:

```
using thrust::get;
if (get<0>(lhs) && get<0>(rhs) ) return get<1>(lhs) <= get<1>(rhs); else 
// we need co check which value should be excluded from the seach
if (get<0>(lhs) == false) // lhs should be excluded so lhs is lesser
                          // OR both should be excluded and no matter what 
                          // we will return it will be eliminated in other comparison
  return true; else
if (get<0>(rhs) == false) // rhs should be excluded so rhs is lesser
  return false;
```

Comment: Thanks. But that did not answer my question completely. Say `operator` returns true. How does the function max element know how to interpret this value `true`. What if the operator returns false? How does the function max element interpret it?

Comment: RTFM. "This version compares objects using a function object comp. Specifically, this version of max_element returns the first iterator i in [first, last) such that, for every iterator j in [first, last), comp(*i, *j) is false." http://docs.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/group__extrema.html#ga90f5158cab04adeb3f1b8b5e4acdbbcc I've already given you this link.

Comment: Okay. the manual says "it returns first iterator i in [first, last) such that, for every iterator j in [first, last), comp(*i, *j) is false." So, shouldn't the comparison be `get<1>(lhs) < get<1>(rhs)` as if there is a duplicate, we should still return false as according to the definition, for every j(which may includes duplicates), comp(*i,*j) should be false

Comment: @Programmer Yes, you are right, but that was just an example of how it may be, or what can it look like, not the exact solution.

Comment: After reading the manual more closely, in the first if `if (get<0>(lhs) && get<0>(rhs) ) `, why do we need the second condition `get<0>(rhs)`. If for a particular i the bool value is false, then won't the condition `if(get<0>(lhs))` prevent the i from being chosen

Comment: In addition to the above question, please also answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006148/function-object-now-working-properly