# Can you pass thrust::device_ptr to thrust::tuple?

Tags: cuda, thrust

Is the below code valid:

```
typedef thrust::device_ptr<int> IntIterator;
typedef thrust::device_ptr<float> FloatIterator;
typedef thrust::tuple<IntIterator,FloatIterator> IteratorTuple;
typedef thrust::zip_iterator<IteratorTuple> myZipIterator;
```

I know below is correct, but in the above case we are using pointers:

```
 typedef thrust::device_vector<float>::iterator       FloatIterator;  
typedef thrust::tuple<FloatIterator, FloatIterator, FloatIterator> FloatIteratorTuple;           
 typedef thrust::zip_iterator<FloatIteratorTuple>                   Float3Iterator;
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you check the validity of the code by attempting to compile and run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, and it works [Your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988603/applying-reduction-operation-using-thrust-subject-to-a-boolean-condition). Moreover, reading compiler error messages, I guess that `thrust::device_vector<type>::iterator` is a typedef of `thrust::device_ptr<type>`.